# Webview didFailLoadWithError error code -999

Tags: ios, webview

In this code, `UIWebView` fails to load, I saw this:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x1c0e36e0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-2/html/container.html#xpc=sf-gdn-exp-3&p=http%3A//blog.moneysmart.sg, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-2/html/container.html#xpc=sf-gdn-exp-3&p=http%3A//blog.moneysmart.sg}

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error 
{}
```

May I know what is the error code -999?

Comment: Refer this url :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451012/uiwebview-not-go-to-didfailloadwitherror-when-weblink-not-found

Answer (score 1):

It actually means that another request is made before the previous request is completed.