# Xcode: Unable to view one URL (no error messages)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xcode7, swift2

I posted this question earlier but it was marked as a duplicate which in my opinion it is not. Here are the details.

I have a view that I use to access 7 URLs. Just one of these URLs does not load. The URL is correct and it loads from iOS Safari. The 6 other URLs load without problem. All URLs are http. How do I debug this? **There are no error messages.**

The suggestion referred to when my previous question was closed as duplicate was that I change NSAppTransportSecurity to NSAllowsArbitraryLoads YES, but that was already the case in info.plist. Is there somewhere else that I need to change ATS?

```
override func viewDidLoad ()
{
super.viewDidLoad ()
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == false
{
    showAlert ()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let returnNC = myStack.pop()
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(returnNC!) 
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else {
    let fullURL  = defaults.objectForKey("URL") as? String
    let url = NSURL(string: fullURL!)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    myWebView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!)      {
print("Webview fail with error \(error)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To track this down, you need more information.  Even though the web page exists in the browser, there may be other issues (such as transient connections / 404 responses, etc.).

UIWebView's didFailLoadWithError() function doesn't return response codes, which could provide some information that can help you debug.  See the answer at this [related StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451012/uiwebview-not-go-to-didfailloadwitherror-when-weblink-not-found).  If you find anything useful, update your question.